# password reset directive in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have to put validation in reset password form using Angular js.
The following link helps my problem:-
http://jsfiddle.net/lsiv568/aRN5h/8/

but in this, the file which contains the directive is full of errors when we run in eclipse. Can anyone solve it, its just an error related to brackets. I am new to Angular JS, so unable to do this.

The code which has errors is here:-

```
'use strict';

 app = angular.module('passwordMatchValidator', [])
 app.directive 'passwordMatch', ->
 require: 'ngModel'
 link: (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) ->

  firstPasswordElement = angular.element(document.getElementById('password-to-verify'))

  checkMatch = ->
    scope.$apply ->
      valid = elem.val() is firstPasswordElement.val()
      ctrl.$setValidity 'passwordMatch', valid

  for theElement in [firstPasswordElement, elem]
    theElement.bind 'keyup', ->
      checkMatch()
 app.controller 'FormCtrl', ($scope) ->
 $scope.resetPassword = (password) ->
 alert 'resetting password'

 angular.bootstrap document, ['passwordMatchValidator']`enter code here`
```

Comment: Are you aware that this CoffeeScript and have you put this code in a CoffeeScript file so that eclipse knows how to parse it?

Comment: this coffee dont make sense check identation